How do I add a character at the end of a field to get the total to 100 characters?
I'm writing an SSRS report for an Association directory.  They would like each line to look like this:
Title...........Name
The characters from the Value of Title and the dots should equal 100 characters.
This is what I have tried so far:
=Left(Fields!TITLE.Value & ".", 100) & Fields!Name.Value
=Fields!TITLE.Value & StrDup(100 - Len(Fields!TITLE.Value), ".") & Fields!Name.Value
Neither of those worked.  Does anyone know how to do this?

This is untested as I can't try it right now but the following should work.
=Fields!TITLE.Value & StrDup(100 - (Len(Fields!TITLE.Value) + Len(Fields!Name.Value)), ".") & Fields!Name.Value

If this does not work, please edit your question and supply some sample data. You may have to wrap all the field references in a TRIM() is there are any leading/trailing spaces in the title or name fields. e.g. all instances of Fields!TITLE.Value would become TRIM(Fields!TITLE.Value)

if it works, please accept the answer

@ArielCrotty As Harry said, if this answers your question, please mark it as accepted. It the check mark to the left of the answer, under the vote up/down buttons. By accepting the answer it helps other users find answers to similar questions. You will also gain reputation which over time, will allow you to do more things on Stackoverflow.
